Moderator Election Coming Soon
I'm happy to announce that this site has been cleared for graduation… congratulations!
Unfortunately, there has been a long backlog of sites waiting for their custom site design, so rather than waiting for that backlog to clear, we are going to start moving ahead and hold the first community-based election of moderators sooner rather than later. 
This is just a heads up to let you know why we're having the election before the graduation and design is ready. The election should start sometime in the next week or so, so watch the announcements on the sidebar for the notice. 
Congratulations again, and enjoy!

Are you upping privileges and adding migration paths as part of this semi-graduation? Yay for migration paths (we have a steady stream for SO and Sec.SE), not so yay for privileges (this is going to hurt the close/reopen review queues).

If we'd go for the same level as InfoSec SE has (concerning reputation needs) only 24 of us would be able to reopen / close vote instead of the current 117. I guess that would be bad as not even all of those 24 are regularly active as far as I can tell.

Rep levels and privileges won't be changing at this time. Just an election will take place - the rest comes when(ever) the design is ready.

What is the current timeframe for custom site design? Who is ahead of us in the queue?

The dangers of having designs that are too similar. (Yes, it used to be even worse.)
